# Something is corrupting my system files especially javascript

Tags: windows-7, javascript, copy-paste

Strange things are happening to my PC.

- My files are corrupting automatically
- Copy paste behave strangely some time

I am a web developer, and I see my JavaScript files are corrupting automatically. I have not touched or edited The files which are getting corrupted . I replaced my corrupted file with backup, but again another JavaScript files get corrupted. Who is doing this all ??

I am using latest ZoneAlrm antivirus.

And some my copy paste paste dont work, it is not keyboard problem (I have 3 KB's, same thing happen with all). Generally I copy from browser. If i copy text from browser and try to paste it in notepad then nothing appear, if I try to pate same copied text in MS office word then it paste a dark circle..

Please tell me why it is happaning

Comment: Could you describe the 'corruption'? There is some chance that your RAM modules are failing, run memtest86+ overnight to check.

Comment: I don't have much trust in ZoneAlarm. Commercial antiviruses are often worse than free ones AFAICT

Comment: @Bob how to run memtest86

Comment: I trust zone alarm, also I have tested my whole HDD by many other antivirus, nothing found by all

Comment: @user1983017 - Regardless of you trusting ZoneAlarm, many people don't.  I would suggest you uninstall it and try [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security-essentials-download).  If nothing else, it gives you another reference point to narrow down from to make it more likely that it isn't a virus.

Comment: @user1983017 Download the ISO [here](http://www.memtest.org/#downiso), burn it, boot from the CD. You should get a blue background with text. Run overnight. See how many passes (recommended at least 5) and errors, and see if there's a list of errors in the bottom half (highlighted red). Even a single error is considered bad.